# How to fix extra blank Excel files after converting from PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

The problem is that after converting from PDF to Excel, when browsing to save the output file it creates additional blank Excel file, no idea why.

If I convert 2 PDF's it outputs 2 converted Excel files and 2 additional blank Excel documents.

Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_To_Excel()
    Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
    Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")
    Dim pdf_path As String
    Dim excel_path As String

    pdf_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.PDF), *.PDF", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

    excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

    Dim objFile As File
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fo As Folder
    Dim f As File
    Set objFile = fso.GetFile(pdf_path)
    sPath = Left(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path) - Len(objFile.Name))
    Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sPath)
    Dim wa As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim wr As Object

    Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
    'Dim wa As New Word.Application
    wa.Visible = False
    'Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim nsh As Worksheet
    'Dim wr As Word.Range

    For Each f In fo.Files
        Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
        Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
        wr.WholeStory

        Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
        Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

        wr.Copy
        nsh.Activate 'Pastespecial like this needs to use an active sheet (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial)
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=1, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

        Dim oILS As Shape
        Set oILS = nsh.Shapes(nsh.Shapes.Count)

        With oILS
            .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 5
            .PictureFormat.CropTop = 150
            .PictureFormat.CropRight = 320
            .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 250
        End With
        With oILS
            .LockAspectRatio = True
        '    .Height = 260
        '    .Width = 450
        End With
        nsh.Shapes(nsh.Shapes.Count).Top = Sheets(1).Rows(1).Top
        Dim IntialName As String
        Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
        'IntialName = "Name.xlsx"
        sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Name.xlsx", "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
        If sFileSaveName <> False Then
          nwb.SaveAs sFileSaveName
          doc.Close True
          nwb.Close True
        End If
Next
wa.Quit
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208531/discussion-on-question-by-nytro-how-to-fix-extra-blank-excel-files-after-convert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that, when you open your pdf file in Word, a temporary file is created. It has the same name but with "_$" prefix. Your code has to work as expected if you modify it adapting the loop as following:

```
For Each f In fo.Files
        If Not Split(f.Name, ".")(1) = "pdf" Or _
                    left(f.Name, 2) = "~$" Then
        Else
            'your existing code follows here....
            '...
        End If
Next
```

If you use dots (.) in your pdf file names, we can find a different approach to extract its extension. If you drop in that folder only pdf files, you can transform the first line in something simpler:

```
If left(f.Name, 2) = "~$" Then
```